# ForerunnerDB AngularJS2 module

Tags: forerunnerdb

ForerunnerDB includes an AngularJS module that allows you to require ForerunnerDB as a dependency in my AngularJS (or Ionic) application. Does this module still work with Ionic2? if yes does it work the same way or somewhat different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did my research and it looks like that the dependency requirement is different in Angular2.